# new Activity Results API and Google Pay

Tags: android, android-activity, google-api, google-pay

Are there any way to wrap [AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/AutoResolveHelper) call into new Activity Results API and get rid of `onActivityResult` handling?

Comment: Are there any news to this? I have the same issue.